# How to make a font appear as is and not pixelated

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using a custom font for a image slider in SharePoint 2010. For some reason when the size of the font is anything bigger than 12pt, the font is pixelated and is not sharp in IE 8.

CSS:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro';
    src: url('http://insidedev:1000/fonts/myriadpro.otf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('http://insidedev:1000/fonts/myriadpro.otf?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('http://insidedev:1000/fonts/myriadpro.otf') format('otf'), /* Modern Browsers */
}
    #slider div.mc-caption {
        font: 13pt bold 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', Verdana, MyriadPro;
        color:#FFFFF;
        z-index:4;
        text-align:left;
        background:none;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #slider div.mc-caption a {
        color: #354B9A;
        font: 13pt bold 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', Verdana, MyriadPro;
    }
    #slider div.mc-caption a:hover {
        color: #E8620E;
        font: 13pt bold 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', Verdana, MyriadPro;
    }
```

I was trying to originally use a custom font, `MyriadPro` but that did not seem to be being used in my image slider. With the above CSS, the caption looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? How do I fix it, please let me know.

Comment: It could just be that the font is bad. I've noticed that custom font's have this issue sometimes. I recently had to stop using 'Ubuntu' from Google Fonts because it started putting some odd shadow around the font at certain sizes in Google Chrome.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and FF and it's working fine.

Comment: IE 8 is terrible at rendering fonts. There is also something that IE uses called ClearType which is a setting in your Browser options, sometimes turning it on or off will change the font rendering, but that is totally up to the user to change. Personally, I do not support IE8 anymore so I just don't go there. Anyone using IE8 has an old computer and is not likely to notice this kind of thing.

Comment: @pathfinder I totally agree with you on that one. Unfortunately a lot of the application we use only works in IE8 (sadly) so no way to upgrade. I did add the ClearType code in my script but I guess like you said if the user doesn't enable it, then it will be pixelated. DAMN IE!!!

Comment: you could use conditional commenting for IE8 to load a css stylesheet to use a font that IE8 likes (a basic sanserif web font) and just load it there.

Comment: Most likely I have to do just that... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem by using ClearType for older version of IE8 that displays the pixelated font.

First, what is ClearType?

> Think of those jagged edges you often see in text on a computer
>   screen, especially any flat-panel. Well, there’s a bit of code in your
>   operating system that attempts to clean up those edges by using
>   anti-aliasing at the sub-pixel level to visually smooth out those
>   rough edges, making the text easier to read. Essentially, it aims to
>   make on-screen text appear more like printed text.
>
> But, here’s where our problem lies. Animating text with JavaScript
>   (especially in jQuery) overrides the ClearType feature by telling the
>   browser to display each step of the pixel throughout animation. When
>   the animation completes, its left displaying the final step without
>   ClearType enabled, leaving the text looking a bit crappy. Functions
>   like fadeIn() and fadeOut() usually trigger the override and cause the
>   pixel problems. (dauid.com)

An example of JavaScript/JQuery that causes ClearType issue:

```
$("#div").fadeIn();
```

To get around the issue, especially for older browsers, you have to remove the `filter` attributes like this:

```
// This fixes the ClearType issue in jQuery

$("#div").fadeIn(function(){
this.style.removeAttribute("filter");
});

// This fixes the ClearType issue in animations outside of jQuery

document.getElementById("#div").style.removeAttribute("filter");
```

Hope it helps others who are experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background colour of the link text to match what is behind it.

```
#slider div.mc-caption a {
        color: #354B9A;
        font: 13pt bold 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', Verdana, MyriadPro;
        background-color:??????
}
```

Comment: For fixing the pixelation issue?

Comment: It didn't fix the issue, still pixelated :/

Comment: I did another way :). Thanks for the help. I will accept the answer because you tried to help.

Comment: Actually, please un-accept the answer. Others will assume it is correct, and it is not.

Comment: In that case this question will remain un answered :/ but good for your honesty :)

Comment: @pnuts It seems in IE8 you have to enable ClearType and the pixelation goes away... Almost :)

Comment: @pnuts I completely agree with you. I will post a solution for my issue. Thanks.